# Sylow subgroup of a profinite group

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of a profinite group of order $lp^n$, where $l$ and $p$ are primes with $l<p$, necessarily normal?

Comment: A profinite group of order $lp^n$ is a *finite* group. Why do you label it as profinite? It is like referring to a compact topological group of order 9 instead of a finite group of order $9$ (as the first reference to the group). Are you aware of the theorem that a subgroup of a finite group $G$ whose index is the smallest prime factor of $|G|$ must be normal?

Comment: If n is finite, since l<p, a Sylow p-subgroup is normal by Sylow Theorem. I donnot know the case n is infinite.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a profinite group of order $lp^\infty$?

Comment: Let $G$ be a profinite group and $p$ a prime. A $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is a subgroup such that $|P|$ is a (possibly infinite)  power of $p$ and $|G:P|$ is coprime to $p$.

Comment: Without further explanation this does not make sense. If $P$ is infinite, then $|P|$ is an infinite cardinal number, and it makes no sense to say that $|P|$ is an infinite power of $p$. Also, $|G:P|$ coprime to $p$ only makes sense if $|G:P|$ is finite. (But Alex Ravsky's answer works provided that $P$ is a $p$-group of finite index $l < p$. There is no need to assume that $G$ is a profinite group.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $P$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$ such that $|G:P|=l$. Define a map $h$ from $G$ to a group $S_P$ of permutations of left cosets of $G$ with respect to $P$ putting $h(g)(aP)=gaP$ for each coset $aP$. Since $h$ is a homomorphism, its kernel $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $x\in P$ be any element. Then order $|h(x)|$ of $h(x)$ is a power of $p$. On the other hand, $|h(x)|$ divides $|h(G)|$ which divides $|S_P|=l!$. Since $l!$ and $p$ are coprime, we have $|h(x)|=1$, that is $x\in N$. So $P\le N$ and thus $|G:N|=1$ or $|G:N|=p$. Since $P\ne G$, a group $h(G)$ is non-trivial, so the former case is impossible. So $|G:N|=p=|G:P|$ and hence $N=P$.

Comment: Thanks very much!